# add a number to all odd or even indexed elements in numpy array without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say your numpy array is:

```
 A =    [1,1,2,3,4]
```

You can simply do:

> A + .1

to add a number to that every element numpy array

I am looking for a way to add a number to just the odd or even indexed numbers `A[::2] +1` while keeping the entire array intact.

Is it possible to add a number to all the odd or even indexed elements without any loops?

Comment: why does it need to be without loops? could you show your code? where you want to implement this in the code?

Comment: What does "while keeping the entire array intact" mean?  Are you ruling out in-place operations?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
In [43]: A = np.array([1,1,2,3,4], dtype = 'float')

In [44]: A[::2]  += 0.1

In [45]: A
Out[45]: array([ 1.1,  1. ,  2.1,  3. ,  4.1])
```

Note that this modifies `A`. If you wish to leave `A` unmodified, copy `A` first:

```
In [46]: A = np.array([1,1,2,3,4], dtype = 'float')

In [47]: B = A.copy()

In [48]: B[::2]  += 0.1

In [49]: B
Out[49]: array([ 1.1,  1. ,  2.1,  3. ,  4.1])

In [50]: A
Out[50]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

Comment: What if we have a 2D array, if j+j is even we add zero?

Answer (score 16):

In addition to previous answers, to modify numbers with odd indices you should use A[1::2] instead of A[::2]

Answer (score 2):

Something with list comprehension could work.

```
A = [1,1,2,3,4]
A = [A[i] + (0 if (i%2 == 0) else .1) for i in range(len(A))]
```

Just quick and dirty with a ternary.  Might not work in your version of Python, can't remember which versions it works with.

---

Checked in Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3, output is the same:

```
>>> A = [1,1,2,3,4]

>>> A
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> A = [A[i] + (0 if (i%2 == 0) else .1) for i in range(len(A))]

>>> A
[1, 1.1, 2, 3.1, 4]
```

Comment: Ah, missed the numpy array bit.  The first answer is much better.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the list didn't start with two 1 and you wanted to add to all even numbers, you could use:

```
A[1::2] += 0.1
```

or

```
A[::-2][::-1] += 0.1
```

In the latter case, [::-1] is used to reverse the array back to normal order.