# how to make numpy array to transform its content

Tags: python

I made a numpy array like below.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 4))
np.array(arr)
```

I want to transform array to two options

1. Even to 1, odd to 0
2. Even to itself, odd to 0

I made some code like these:

(1)

```
odd = (arr % 2 == 1)
even = (arr % 2 == 0)
def transform1(array):
     array[odd] = 0
     array[even] = 1

mat1 = transform1(arr)
print(mat1)
```

(2)

```
odd = (arr % 2 == 1)
even = (arr % 2 == 0)

def transform2(array):
   array[odd] = 0

mat2 = transform2(arr)    
print(arr)
```

but they didn't work for my purpose.
How can I solve it witout using for statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add a number to all odd or even indexed elements in numpy array without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849778/add-a-number-to-all-odd-or-even-indexed-elements-in-numpy-array-without-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mat1 = np.where(arr % 2, 0, 1)
mat2 = np.where(arr % 2, 0, arr)
```

Look [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where) to see how `np.where()` works. It's pretty much equivalent to:

```
mat1 = np.empty(shape=arr.shape, dtype=int)
mat2 = np.empty(shape=arr.shape, dtype=int)
for i in range(mat1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mat1.shape[1]):
        mat1[i][j] = 0 if arr[i][j] % 2 else 1
        mat2[i][j] = 0 if arr[i][j] % 2 else arr[i][j]
```